# How to delete records from many-to-many (secondary) table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having problems deleting records from `PostTag` table that contains `Post` and `Tag` column. This is my relation table:

```
tags = db.Table('PostTag',
    db.Column('Tag', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Tag.Id')),
    db.Column('Post', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Post.Id'))
)
```

and

```
tags = db.relationship(Tag, secondary=tags, backref=db.backref('Post', lazy='dynamic'))
```

When I do this:

```
from models.Post import Post

posts = Post.query.join(Post.tags).filter(Post.Id == id).all()
if(posts):
   return posts
return False
```

and then

```
for posttag in post[0].tags:
    db.session.delete(posttag)
    db.session.flush()
```

Rows from many-to-many relation are deleted but also records from `Tag` table.

I just need to delete records from `PostTag` table for some condition (`Post=1` for example)

I searched the internet but I did not find anything conclusive. I do not need cascade on many-to-many relationship.

This is sql log:

```
 297 Query  DELETE FROM `PostTag` WHERE `PostTag`.`Tag` = 14 AND `PostTag`.`Post` = 3
 297 Query  DELETE FROM `PostTag` WHERE `PostTag`.`Tag` = 14 AND `PostTag`.`Post` = 18
 297 Query  DELETE FROM `Tag` WHERE `Tag`.`Id` = 14
```

Last row `297 Query DELETE FROM`Tag`WHERE`Tag`.`Id`= 14` should not be there.

**UPDATE / maybe solution**

I kind of solved this with:

```
sql = 'DELETE FROM PostTag WHERE Post=%s'
db.engine.execute(sql, post, ())
```

But that is not just ORM way. Same goes for insert. I will try to get this resolved ORM way. I will post answer if I make this problem go away.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
post = db.session.query(Post).get(1)
post.tags = []
db.session.commit()
```

Here we are redefining the collection `post.tags` to the empty array and committing the changes. To explain this I'll refer to the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/collections.html#custom-collection-implementations):

> Collections in SQLAlchemy are transparently instrumented. Instrumentation means that normal operations on the collection are tracked and result in changes being written to the database at flush time.

So SQLAlchemy keeps track of the changes we make to the collection post.tags and updates it on commit.

If we had only one tag (say `sometag`) we could use the `remove` method like this:

```
post = db.session.query(Post).get(1)
post.tags.remove(sometag)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Could you explain why this does not work?
`tags = post.tags
tags = []`

Comment: It updates it into commit, but if you take a look into what happens on db. It's actually sending in my case 4000 deletions. While it could send one.

Comment: what is sometag? an id? name? an object?

Comment: it only removes the records on association table not in Tags table, in my case, could you please give some solution to also remove records on Tags table?

Answer (score 11):

Try to remove objects from the collection instead:

```
post[0].tags.clear()
```

You could also remove individual items:

```
post[0].tags.remove(posttag)
```

Comment: "post[0].tags.clear()" - this does not work for me.  I get the following:

AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'clear'

Comment: I can't find any clear() function in the SQLAlchemy documentation. Can you provide a link to the docs?

Comment: Thanks, clear() worked for me on a similar problem.